# phonegap build: video and audio file not found

Tags: android, cordova, audio, video

I am uploading a zip-file onto phonegap build which contains a video folder containing video files and an audio folder containing audio files on the same level as the config.xml file. When I start the app and debug it, I can see that the apps looks for the files in `android_asset/www/video` and `android_asset/www/audio` . When I unzip the .apk file, the video and audio folder and the videos and audio files are not there.

How do I have to structure the zip file so that the video and audio files become accessible? Why does phonegap build not include the videos and audio files in the .apk?

**EDIT**

My current structure

```
- config.xml
- index.html
- res
-- icon
-- screen
- js
- css
- audio
- video
```

I also tried

```
- config.xml
- index.html
- res
-- icon
-- screen
-- raw
--- audio
--- video
- js
- css
```

Comment: What is the current structure do you have?

Comment: @JoseRojas thanks for your reply. I edited the question, it now shows the structures I have tried.

Comment: Your icon appear at the .apk file when you're installing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling from the website build.phonegap.com, Try with this structure:

```
myApp/
|-- config.xml
|-- hooks/
|-- merges/
| | |-- android/
| | |-- blackberry10/
| | `-- ios/
|-- www/
|-|--index.html
| | |--audio/
| | |--video/
|-- platforms/
| |-- android/
| |-- blackberry10/
| `-- ios/
`-- plugins/
```